# jQuery: removing elements and what about the event listener?

Tags: jquery, event-listener

Just curious, what happends to the event Listener

```
$('a.someclass', 'div.contextClass').on('click', function someFunction(){
    console.log('clicked!');
});
```

when I remove div.contextClass

```
$('div.contextClass').remove();
```

Do I first need to do this?

```
$('a.someclass', 'div.contextClass').off('click');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

When the `context` or `parent` (`<div>`) itself is removed, everything within it (`<a>`) gets removed from the DOM. The event handler only executes the handler when the event takes place.

But when the element itself is not present, it gets no events which can then be handled because you don't have the element to do something like `click` or `focus` or something.

Comment: Destroyed is probably not the good word, but +1 since it answer the question.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon "removed" maybe?

Comment: @AmitJoki Better, destroyed make it sound like it no longer exist, which is not the case.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon The things is... are there situations where the eventlisteners are kept in the browsers memory? Memory leak stuff? But I guess the main question is answered...

Comment: @poashoas The event listener will be removed, the data of the element will be erased, but the element will still exist in the memory. Since there is no events and no datas bound to it, it will take less space.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon So infinite scrolling like on tumblr is actualy a bad idea. Memory could get... busy?

Comment: @poashoas I don't think so.. sooner or later I suppose it will be garbage collected as in other languages

Comment: @poashoas Usually, infinite scroller arent deleting node... I don't know about tumbler though. In my experience, after some time, you see a bouton that will "change page" to refresh the memory. As for the garbage collector mentioned above, I am not aware if JS has one.... Anyway, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwkm4oe2/), open the memory tab in the inspector and see for yourself. The memory keep getting up, but the number of node is always the same. Run it long enough to see if there is a garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to jquery reference documents [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you
>   want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. **In
>   addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data
>   associated with the elements are removed**. To remove the elements
>   without removing data and events, use .detach() instead.